# pip перестал работать

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.7

Из-за чего-то перестал работать `pip`. Всё, что находила в гугле не помогает. 
По умолчанию версия питона  `python -V` - **Python 3.7.3**.

При вводе команды `pip -V` вылетает ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

При вводе команды `pip3 -V` вылетает ошибка:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fc278ab4740 (most recent call first):
Аварийный останов (стек памяти сброшен на диск)
```

Сам по себе **Python 3.7.3** работает, но устанавливать пакеты и использовать их невозможно.

Comment: Сколько и какие версии python у вас установлены?

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, проблема в нескольких версиях Питона на устройстве.
Попробуйте явно указать ту версию, что вам нужна через эти переменные `PYTHONPATH` и `PYTHONHOME`

`export PYTHONPATH='/path/to/pythondir:/path/to/pythondir/lib-dynload:/path/to/pythondir/site-packages'`

`export PYTHONHOME='/path/to/pythondir'`

Comment: и дополню, что одно из лучших решений это использование [virtual enviroment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).